# How to get Star Rating from JPEG files in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, metadata, python-imaging-library, exif

How can I get the star rating info from a jpeg file in python? I've looked through the EXIF info and did not find anything indicating the star rating. However, I can see it in the windows file explorer. Are there anyways that I can get that information with some python packages?

Comment: Windows uses the `0x4747` and `0x4749` tags to store ratings. See http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html.